# DTOs in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm making an angular project using asp.net for the back-end. So I want to make use of data transfer objects in angular but I'm having problems replicating the navigation properties. Is there anyway to do this?

My DTOs so far:

```js
import { DocumentsDto } from './DocumentsDto';

export class CaseFilesDto {
    idCaseFile: number;
    CaseFileName: string;
    CreationDate: Date;
    CaseFileOwner: string;
    AmountOfDocuments: number;
    Document: DocumentsDto[];

    public CaseFilesDto() {
        this.Document = new DocumentsDto[];
    }
}

import { CaseFilesDto } from './CaseFilesDto';

export class DocumentsDto {
    idDocument: number;
    idCaseFile: number;
    DocumentName: string;
    CreationDate: Date;

    CaseFile: CaseFilesDto;
}
```

The problem here is in the line where it puts:

```js
this.Document = new DocumentsDto[];
```

Using tslint on visual studio code I get that the error is that documentsDto misses the include property. But I can't find such thing.

Thank you!

Regards.

Comment: As a note, constructor syntax is different in TypeScript than it is in C#. Instead of using the class name as the constructor name, you name the function `constructor` (i.e. `public constructor() {...}` instead of `public CaseFilesDto() {...}`). https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the line to

```
this.Document = [];
```

In javascript and typescript you can create a new array just like that. You could even simplify it a bit like this.

```
export class CaseFilesDto {
    idCaseFile: number;
    CaseFileName: string;
    CreationDate: Date;
    CaseFileOwner: string;
    AmountOfDocuments: number;
    // Initialize the value
    Document: DocumentsDto[] = [];
}
```